# Solving speed problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A motorist, travelling at 100 km/h, overtakes an 4WD towing a caravan. The 4WD and caravan together are 13 metres long and have a speed of 64 km/h. The car is 5 metres long. How many seconds will it take from the time the front of the car is level with the back of the caravan to the time the back of the car is level with the front of the 4WD?

The ans is 1.8s.

Comment: You could start by making two drawings on a sheet of paper. One with the front of the car level with the back of the caravan, one with the back of the car level with the front of the towing car.

Comment: at time $t_0$ the front of the car is level with the back of the caravan; at time $t_1$ the back of the car is level with the front of the 4WD; from $t_0$ to $t_1$ the car has to travel $(13 + 5)$ m and considering the caravan to be stationary for calculation purpose then the car is travelling at a speed of $(100-64)$ km/h, now we know the speed of the car and the distance it has to travel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: you can assume that the 4WD and caravan aren't moving. At what speed is the motorist travelling now?

Hint2: the speeds of the two participants are constant. So, you can assume that only the motorist is moving with $100\hspace{0.1cm}km/h - 64\hspace{0.1cm}km/h = 36\hspace{0.1cm}km/h$.